# How to display the tabs inline in the Action Bar

Tags: android

Is there any way to instead of icons and labels of activities display the tabs (I'd like to have done it, but couldn't find any solution). I'm trying display the navigation tabs inside the activity bar (not under) at a vertical display orientation (portrait). I looked android library "ActionBarSherlock", an example of "Styled", but there are tabs display exactly the same as in the standard package.

### Examples of Activity Bar ("portrait" orientation):

Standard display the tabs in the Activity Bar

```
+------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| +---+                                                              /˜\    +  |
| |   | Example                                                      \_/    +  |
| +---+                                                                \    +  |
+------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|                         |                          |                         |
|        Section 1        |        Section 2         |        Section 3        |
|                         |                          |                         |
+------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

An example of how it would look like (Activity Bar without icon and label, with tabs inside)

```
+------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|       |       |                                                    /˜\    +  |
| Tab 1 | Tab 2 | Tab 3                                              \_/    +  |
|       |       |                                                      \    +  |
+------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

It would be great if someone could tell me how I can implement this in the range versions 2.2 to 4.0. Please, help me with this problem.

Comment: can't help but +1 for ascii art.

Comment: Then i guess you'll have to create your own actionbar.

Answer (score 0):

When you rotate the screen to landscape mode it will display the way want. In portrait mode it will display the tabs in stacked mode. There really isn't enough room to do what you want in portrait mode on a phone (even something like the S3) and the android SDK knows that.

If you're dead set on doing this in portrait mode you should look into custom title bar layout (ActionBarSherlock has demos of this).